# Error Response Contrainer is not running

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to Create and Join channel by entering into cli container using command : docker exec -it cli bash

But, i am getting following error response :

Error Response from daemon : Container dasdjha343343xxxxx is not running.

Comment: You will need to share the log output from the peer container to ascertain why it may have failed. Use 'docker logs <containerid>'.

Some ideas. If you previously ran the sample, you may want to be sure that you destroy the previous containers. Follow the directions for tearing down your environment.

Comment: I am getting attached error while trying to access docker logs  /bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token 'pick_a_value'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: ./scripts/script.sh mychannel ; sleep (pick_a_value)'

Comment: can you please share the following outputs: 1) 'docker ps' 2) 'docker ps -a'

Comment: a63815df0b34        dev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0-26c2ef32838554aac4f7ad6f
100aca865e87959c9a126e86d764c8d01f8346ab   "chaincode -peer.a..."   About an hou
r ago   Up About an hour                                                       d
ev-peer1.org2.example.com-mycc-1.0
a0caf36a4a7e        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0-384f11f484b9302df90b4532
00cfb25174305fce8f53f4e94d45ee3b6cab0ce9   "chaincode -peer.a..."

Comment: a0caf36a4a7e        dev-peer0.org1.example.com-mycc-1.0-384f11f484b9302df90b4532
00cfb25174305fce8f53f4e94d45ee3b6cab0ce9   "chaincode -peer.a..."

Comment: "peer node start"        About an hou
r ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp     p
eer1.org1.example.com
a02b8d72df6a        hyperledger/fabric-peer
                                           "peer node start"        About an hou
r ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp     p
eer0.org1.example.com

Comment: The formatting is lost, and I think I only see the 'docker ps' output, because I don't see any images for the cli container.

Try using 'docker run cli -it bash' instead.

Comment: $ docker run cli -it bash
Unable to find image 'cli:latest' locally C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for cli, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.

Comment: ok, so likely the container was never created. May I ask whether you are attempting to run one of the fabric-samples? If so, which one? Are you trying to do this on your own following some guide?

Comment: I am following this :http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html and stuck on Create and Join channel where i have to run docker exec cli -it bash

Comment: I am struggling to understand how you got to this point. I suspect that the cli container executed and exited after it ran the scripts/script.sh. If you want to run the steps manually, you need to modify the docker-compose-cli.yaml to comment out the command as instructed. You can always re-run the "docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d" command and it will only restart what is not running.

Answer (score 1):

First stop all your running containers and remove them, try to rerun the exact container, and lastly, when you try to bash to explicit container on Windows.10 use $winpty

```
$docker stop $(docker ps -a -q)
$docker ps -qa|xargs docker rm
$cd fabric-samples/first-network
$docker-compose -f docker-compose-cli.yaml up -d
$winpty docker exec -it cli bash
```

Answer (score 0):

In your working folder, update to latest version by:
 $ git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git

Newer version should resolve this issue.